# Which way to custom magento website

Tags: magento2

I am confused about how to custom magento website. I am a software developer.
I know we have admin panel and frontend.

There are two ways to custom magento website?

e.g. 
 If I want to change the copyright info of magento website.

1. One way, for non-developer, go to admin panel to edit copyright info.
2. Another way, for developer, directly go to source code to edit copyright info? If we can, how can I find this file to change copyright info? I search in the project, cannot find something like 'Copyright © 2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved'

Why a lot of online tutorial is talking about go to admin panel to make the change???

Answer (score 1):

Through the admin panel is the correct way to handle this. The reference to the copyright line is in the footer template.  It's left to the admin to customize to make it easier to update each year as well as adjust the company name for languages or separate companies running from the same code base.

Comment: We cannot change it in source code? As developer, I want to directly change it in the source code. I search in the source code, which does not exist such file that can be edited for that.

Comment: You can.  In your custom theme, just create or edit the template file: `html/copyright.phtml ` and replace the `echo` PHP code with whatever you want.

Comment: Where is the path for that file? I just cannot find it. I search in my project using "2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved". But just cannot find that file. Looks like magento folder structure is very confusing for beginners. I followed this tutorial:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

Comment: The copyright text isn't in that file, it's just a call to a block method to output the admin configured copyright text.  The full path from magento 2 base directory: `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/copyright.phtml `.  You should override this in your own theme though.  To do that, see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html.  The specific line you're looking for is: `echo $block->getCopyright()`.

Comment: Can you let me know where is the file that contains this sentences ""2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved""? I am very confused why I cannot find it in project file.

Comment: There is **no** file which contains the string of text '2017 Magento, Inc.  All rights reserved'.  That string is contained within the store configuration, which you already knew in your OP.  You can either change the text in the configuration of Magento, or you can change the template file which is calling `$block->getCopyright()` to remove that call.  That method just reads the configuration value and returns the string.  You **will not** find that string anywhere in Magento.